# c++ list no type error

Tags: c++, list

so I had this code:

```
    #include <list>

void j(){
    list<int> first;
}
```

but then I get this error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `list' with no type
error: expected `;' before '<' token
```

what did I do wrong lol....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Types and functions in the C++ Standard Library are in the `std` namespace.

This means that the type you are looking for is `std::list<int>`.

---

You can avoid having to write `std::` by using either of the following in the same scope:

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::list;
```

(Now you can just write `list<int>`, because the type has been *brought into scope* from the `std` namespace.)

The former is sometimes frowned-upon; both ought to be avoided in headers.

Comment: +1 Or just add `#include <list>` ;) Sometimes, finding such answers to our problems on SO is a signal that it may be time to go back home and rest ;-)

Comment: @Offirmo Question says the OP already has `#include <list>` :P

Comment: Missing `#include <list>` was *my* problem that led me on this question. I mentionned it for fellow googlers. Indeed that was not the problem here. (Reading my previous comment, I agree that I was unclear.)

Answer (score 1):

Either do:

```
std::list<int> first;
```

or put `using namespace std;` somewhere above your function. All the standard containers are declared in the `std` namespace to avoid naming clashes with user code.

The first method (explicit namespace) is a bit better for the same reason, but that's more a matter of taste.